# Log4Net create file with date

Tags: c#, .net, logging, .net-core, log4net

I using log4net in my .NET Core Console App

Here is my config file

```
    <log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="C:\AVSPL\LogFile.log"/>
        <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
        <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
        <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date"/>
        <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyy.MM.dd"/>
        <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="true"/>
        <maximumFileSize value="25MB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <!-- minimum level to log -->
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

I tried to make log file to append date, but it still creating name `LogFile`, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the attribute `type="log4net.Util.PatternString"` to the file element.
In addition, you should set the `staticLogFileName` to `false`.

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\AVSPL\LogFile.log"/>
<staticLogFileName value="false" />
```

More [info](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Util_PatternString.htm).

Comment: like this `<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\AVSPL\LogFile.log"/>`?